# AngularJS improve first loading of landing page, deffer loading of other scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, lazy-loading

My angular app uses quite a lot of modules which are all needed to be included before my app.js file (where the main app lies) and am using ui-view, due to that the first load takes quite some time because it has to wait for all the dependent modules to load first, before loading the app so that the views can show up.

Is there any way i can prevent that, like loading the app first and defer the loading of the modules ?

Or at least not to have to all the modules from the beginning but as needed.

```
<html>
<body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/xeditable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dirPagination.js"></script>
    <script src="//npmcdn.com/ui-grid-auto-fit-columns@latest/dist/autoFitColumns.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/csv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/excel-builder.dist.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Preferably I'd like solution that will  not require huge changes in the project.

Comment: Angular provides lazy loading of modules: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
Also you should include your libs in your angular-cli.json, that results in fewer requests for the inital load: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Comment: @Daniel. Seems like OP is asking about AngularJS, the reference provided are for Angular.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Comment: start with combining all your js into one file using some build tool -- then you can see if it worth to do something else.